# Change mindate dynamically in Easepick datepicker

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set minday dynamicllay using easepick datepicker, I have tried setting a variable for minday and it works the first time but when I change the variable and open datepicker it doesn't change the mindate. I understand that renderAll() should be used to redraw but I am not sure to which event it should be placed in. The setMinDate is dynamic and depends on what the user selects.

```
            const picker = new easepick.create({
                setup(picker) {
                    picker.on('select', (e) => {
                        picker.renderAll()
                    });
                    picker.on('select', (e) => {
                        const {
                            view,
                            date,
                            target
                        } = e.detail;
                        $('.rateStart').html(moment(e.detail.start).format('DD MMM'))
                        $('.rateEnd').html(moment(e.detail.end).format('DD MMM'))
                        sessionStorage.setItem('endDateTempRate', e.detail.end);
                        sessionStorage.setItem('startDateTempRate', e.detail.start);
                    });
                },
                calendars: 2,
                inline: true,
                element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
                css: [
                    '../assets/css/easepick.css'
                ],
                plugins: ['RangePlugin', 'LockPlugin'],
                RangePlugin: {
                    tooltipNumber(num) {
                        return num - 1;
                    },
                    locale: {
                        one: 'night',
                        other: 'nights',
                    },
                },
                LockPlugin: {
                    minDate: setMinDate,
                    minDays: 2,
                    inseparable: true,
                    filter(date, picked) {
                        if (picked.length === 1) {
                            const incl = date.isBefore(picked[0]) ? '[)' : '(]';
                            return !picked[0].isSame(date, 'day') && date.inArray(bookedDates, incl);
                        }
                        return date.inArray(bookedDates, '[)');
                    },
                }
            });
```

`

`picker.on('show', (e) => { picker.renderAll() });`

I tried to redraw the picker using show event so that the new minday variable will passed to the minday but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like from the [source](https://github.com/easepick/easepick/blob/e33a7f4e4ec1a8b15557ea864445923a278bc88b/packages/core/src/core.ts#L391), you need to supply the calendar to redraw. Have you tried passing the date?

`picker.renderAll(picker.calendar[0])`